# WebSphere Multiple SSL Version Support

Tags: ssl, websphere, ssl-certificate

I'm running a web application that communicates with various APIs. One API requires TLSv1.2 while another will not support something that current (TLSv1 or TLSv1.1).

**Does Websphere support multiple SSL versions?**

I've found documentation about successfully changing the version of SSL, however I really need to be able to run TLSv1.1 and 1.2 together (if that's even possible) or run one version for one application while another for another application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/206952/how-do-i-configure-websphere-application-server-ss/) for setting up SSL in WebSphere, to support the use of TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2, I need to enable `SSL_TLSv2`:

> **Question: WAS is act SSL client, What does remote SSL server support
>   only TLSv1.0 or TLSv1.1 and Similar WAS is act SSL Server, What does
>   Remote SSL client does support only TLSv1.0 or TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2.
>   What to do in order to work such environments?**
>
> Answer: There is an alternative option, SSL_TLSv2, which will enable
>   support for TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1, and TLSv1.2 in the environment. Please
>   use this setting SSL_TLSv2 in environments where support for multiple
>   TLS protocols is required, or if you are not sure whether your WAS
>   environment interacts with other servers or clients using non-TLSv1.2
>   protocols then, you can configure WAS to use SSL_TLSv2 using same
>   steps as given in the above.
>
> Note:
>
> Without poddle fix and configured WAS to use SSL_TLSv2
>
> **SSL_TLSv2 ==> Enables all SSL v3.0 and TLS v1.0, v1.1 and v1.2
>   protocols.** Accepts SSLv3 or TLSv1 hello encapsulated in an SSLv2
>   format hello.
>
> If you installed Poddle fix (will disable SSLv3 ) and configured WAS
>   to use SSL_TLSv2
>
> **SSL_TLSv2 ==> Enables these three TLS v1.0, v1.1 and v1.2 protocols.**

So, changing the QoS settings to `SSL_TLSv2` allows SSL Handshakes to multiple TLS versions when required.

Comment: Adding that the fix for POODLE is in effect from v7.0.0.37, v8.0.0.10 & v8.5.5.4 of WAS. Any version of WAS above these will have SSLv3 disabled, and will default to the TLSv1 protocol.